# angular: centralised resource factory with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, angularjs-scope, promise

Let's say I have a resource that looks like this:

```
angular.module('productsModule').factory('productFactory', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/products/:id',{},
    {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }});
});
```

And now I can use this in a controller like so:

```
productFactory.query().$promise.then(function(products) {
    // success
    console.log(products);
    $scope.products = products;
});
```

However, I'd like to move that functionality to the factory so that I could do this in any controller and it would get me the product list while maintaining the promises:

```
$scope.products = productFactory.products
```

This way I could have a centralised reusable resource. How can I achieve this in Angular?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. What about `$scope.products = productFactory.query()`?

Answer (score 1):

You actually *can* do this with ngResource, while native promises no longer unwrap you can simply do:

```
 $scope.products = productFactory.query();
```

This is because doing `.query` on an ngResource will return an empty array that will automatically popular when the request is returned to the client and will run a digest.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('productsModule').factory('productFactory', function($resource) {
    var res = $resource('/products/:id',{},
               {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false }});
    var fn = function ($scope, prop) {
        res.query().$promise.then(function (products) {
            $scope[prop] = products;
        }
    }

    return fn;
});
```

In the controller:

```
productFactory($scope, 'products');
```